# "Failed to create process" while using R extension at VScode platform

Tags: r, vscode-extensions

running R Document coding at VScode faced a error called "Fail to create process".However, the Terminal at the bottom of VScode interface works well, and auto completion of "languageServer" also works well at the R document  of VScode.
And, following the error information, I found that there is no folder called "tempcoderunnerfile.r" at my TEMP folder.
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arf33.png)][[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1uvq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTNIM.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4vyZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UJ6h.png)

I have followed the online instruction to insert R into VScode. Environmental Variable,Radian and Interpreter Path are all settled